# How to create Multitenant Facebook App to access multiple Pages of different accounts

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to Create a Facebook app which can be integrated with our CRM system to access post, reply to posts, comments etc; along with contact ID, name, Email etc..
The problem I am facing is for each customer new app needs to be created and it has to go through app review process.

Is there any way to create a multi tenant app in Facebook.

Comment: Multiple users can log into the same app, why would you need an app for each customer? Are you talking about branding / custom domain name issues, or what exactly?

Comment: Graph API using Facebook App you can connect your page and start reading the posts; my question is instead of having individual app for each customer for their pages, can I have a universal app which can connect to any Facebook page t0 fetch the data

Comment: Any _user_ can log in to your app, and then you can access the pages they manage.